# Login with facebook and using oauth 2.0 for authentication of REST api calls

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-social

I am using spring framework and REST architecutre in my api. Currently I am authenticating my REST call by sending username and password with every call. And users are stored in my database.

Now I plan to use oauth 2.0 for access to my protected resources and also i plan to use Facebook Login as authentication mechanism.

I have read about spring-security-oauth2 and have implemented in a small example it works fine.

I have read about spring-social and also have implemented it and can access facebook api.

Now all I want to know is how can i login with facebook and then use oauth 2.0 to protect my 
resources.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: What are you having trouble with

Comment: @SajitKunnumkal Using facebook api gives me facebook access token while authenticating with oauth 2.0 requires a token generated by oauth 2.0. Now i am confused how can i use facebook access token to authenticate requests to my api's protected resources.

Answer (score 3):

You would not want to use the Facebook-issued access token to secure your own resources. The Facebook token represents a 3-way agreement between your application, Facebook, and your user. If you want to use OAuth to secure your own resources, that's a completely different agreement between the consumer of those resources, your server, and the user who owns those resources on your server.

Think of it this way: When you are consuming Facebook's API, your application (A) is the consumer, Facebook (FB) is the provider, and there's a common user (U1) that joins those together. But when someone is consuming resources on your server, then your application (A) is in the role of the provider, some other application (X) is the consumer, and there's a common user (U2) who joins those together. It may be the same human (e.g., U1 == U2) that agreed to the arrangement in both cases, but the roles of provider and consumer have changed.

I imagine that there's probably a way to get Spring Security for OAuth to issue the same access token that Facebook issued, but that's not really a good idea.

Comment: so i want to login to my oauth protected api through facebook login, How can i achieve that then?

Comment: What is normally done here is that your user would authenticate to your application's human-facing HTML front-end via Facebook. This would result in Facebook issuing an access token with which you'd authenticate the user. Spring Social's ProviderSignInController or SocialAuthenticationFilter can help there. Once authenticated to your app, they'd authorize some client of your API to access the API on their behalf. That'd result in S2OAuth issuing an access token to the client.

Comment: A common example (not necessarily using Spring Social or S2OAuth, however) of this approach is Foursquare. You can signin to Foursquare via Facebook. And you can authorize some other client to access Foursquare on your behalf. But those are 2 different authorizations and 2 diff. agreements being made. Another example of this approach that does use Spring is Greenhouse (https://github.com/SpringSource/greenhouse).

Comment: I'm in the same position as the OP, having essentially the same requirement. I think my difficulty is understanding the various players in the oauth dance and what role they play. As I see it, I have a REST api, and there will be a client to it (as yet unwritten, but likely to be a web client with angularjs). And I want users to be authenticated with facebook. If they are authenticated by facebook, then they are authorised to use the REST api. Based on this, I dont understand why I wouldnt want to use a facebook issued token ??