# User authentication through my REST API and Facebook

Tags: node.js, rest, authentication, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I'm a bit confused about how to properly and securely authenticate users using my REST API and provide and option to authenticate using other OAuth 2.0 providers as well (e.g. Facebook, Google, etc.).

**Scenario**

Users interact with a web application which should consume my REST API. Users should be able to login and perform CRUD operations both using username/password and by using 3rd party services such as Facebook. I will be using SSL to encrypt the traffic to the website and the API.

Without taking the 3rd party login services in consideration and by studying the various questions already asked here on SO, I thought about handling user authentication as in the picture.

[image: Authentication Sequence]

**Technologies and current idea**

The REST API is written using JS using NodeJS and Express. The WebApp provided through another NodeJS instance is mostly AngularJS with templates which consumes the REST API.

My current idea is to let the WebApp handle the login sequence and let Facebook save their token in my DB using the callback. But this solution smells too much of workaround!

**Questions**

1. Is the authentication sequence depicted in the image correct?
2. How is the above authentication sequence compared to the Resource Owner Password Credential flow in OAuth2.0? Is it worth using OAuth2.0 instead of it?
3. How can I integrate login through 3rd parties (i.e. Facebook)? Any suggestion or (better) example?

**References**

[passport.js RESTful auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572600/passport-js-restful-auth)

[Login with facebook and using oauth 2.0 for authentication of REST api calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14839183/login-with-facebook-and-using-oauth-2-0-for-authentication-of-rest-api-calls)

And many others here on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents..

1. The process looks good to me.. I would re-issue the token on each sign in and also keep it inside a database so tokens can be revoked easily.

Use PassportJS. Its got support for OAuth flows and supports many 3rd party integrations like FB, Twitter, Github etc..and since its a nodejs middleware.. its integration will be very tight within your application..